# How to list array names in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have arrays within arrays in json. is there anyway in which i can list the name of an array. if one array exists which contains 5 other array is there a way to list all the names 5 array, not their content but their names. is there a way to do this in javascript

for example

hey, i got the jist of your answer but i just want to clarify. i have json as follows,

```
{
"array1":[ { 
      "array2":[ { 
              "array3":[ ] } ],
      "array21:[ {
 }]
 } 

] 
}
```

I wanted to know that first i list all the arrays in array1 then all the arrays in array2 then all the arrays in array3. like if i list all the arrays in array1 i should get the result array2 and array2 and so on. is this possible? according to your answer arrays cannot be named hence its not possible but just clarifying

Comment: Arrays are, on their own, anonymous -- just ordered collections of elements. So, what name(s) are you referring to? Are they contained within Objects as values of particular keys? Can you please clarify your question with a sample of the data and the output you expect from it?

Comment: Are you asking how to print their *key*? Did you try a Google (it's the biggest search engine in the world) search for "javascript object list keys"?

Comment: @Jonathan i have updated the answer. Sorry i was not clear before.I hope i am now. Is what I am trying possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding usage of data types. Array is an anonymous type, you don't name it's elements. If you want to know name of an array, then you must change this structure to a dictionary (map).

```
var arrayMapping = {
'arr1': [...],
'arr2': [...]
};
```

But by doing so remember that every array will have unique name. You will then could access your arrays like so:

```
arrayMapping['array1']
```

But if for some reason you can't change this data structure then you need to create a help object, where you are mapping names to arrayIndex. But that will increase code complexity, and will need to be wrapped in some sort of util class with getters.

If your array contains 5 arrays and you want to get to them by name, then you need this sort of a structure:

```
var arrayMapping = {
'arr1': {
   'arr1_1': [],
   'arr1_2': [],
   'arr1_3': [],
   'arr1_4': [],
   'arr1_5': [],
    },
...
};
```

Not if you want to list all anmes of arrays that are inside arr1 map, then you should do something like this:

```
 Object.keys(arrayMapping['arr1'])// it will list arr1_1,...,arr1_5
```

Comment: hey, i got the jist of your answer but i just want to clarify. i have json as follows,      {"array1":[ { "array2":[ { "array3":[ ] } ],"array21:[ { }] } ] },    i wanted to know that first i list all the arrays in array1 then all the arrays in array2 then all the arrays in array3. like if i list all the arrays in array1 i should get the result array2 and array2 and so on. is this possible? according to your answer arrays cannot be named hence its not possible but just clarifying

Comment: I have updated my post. Hope it will answer your problem. If you are confused, then read more about map/dictionary and array data structures. Understanding them will help you:)